# NullPointerException when referencing schema of Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working on this use case that involves converting DStreams to Dataframes after some transformations. I've simplified my code into the following snippet so as to reproduce the error. Also, I've mentioned below my environment settings.

Environment:

- Spark Version: 2.2.0
- Java: 1.8
- Execution mode: local/ IntelliJ

Code:

```
object Tests {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val spark: SparkSession =  ...

import spark.implicits._

    val df = List(
        ("jim", "usa"), 
        ("raj", "india"))
        .toDF("name", "country")

    df.rdd
      .map(x => x.toSeq)
      .map(x => new GenericRowWithSchema(x.toArray, df.schema))
      .foreach(println)
  }
}
```

This results in NullPointerException as I'm directly using `df.schema` in `map()`.

What I don't understand is that if I use the following code (basically storing the schema as a value before transforming), it works just fine.

Modified Code:

```
object Tests {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val spark: SparkSession =  ...

import spark.implicits._

    val df = List(
        ("jim", "usa"), 
        ("raj", "india"))
        .toDF("name", "country")
    val sc = df.schema

    df.rdd
      .map(x => x.toSeq)
      .map(x => new GenericRowWithSchema(x.toArray, sc))
      .foreach(println)
  }
}
```

I wonder why this is happening as `df.rdd` is not an action and there is visible change in state of DataFrame just yet.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: you can't perform actions inside transformations. df.schema is an action whereas map is a transformation. you can perform actions on transformed data and not while transforming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because Apache Spark doesn't permit accessing non-local `Datasets` from executors and behavior is expected.

In contrast, when you extract schema to variable, it is just a local object which can be safely serialized.